# Is there a way to add a cooldown to my code using setTimeout so that people don't spam the command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i just want a way to add a 15 minute cooldown to this whenever a user tries to run it....

if the command is on cooldown is there a way to send a message like *'you are on a cooldown of (timeremaining)'*

The code that i have right now

````
var Money = (Money == null) ? 0: Money+= Math.floor(Math.random()*99) + 1;
Money += Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
$halt
$random{|||||||||Use /bal to check your balance||}
**Balance: $$get(Money)**```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use promise to do the sequential process and cooldown:

```js
var delay = function(s){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     setTimeout(resolve,s); 
    });
  };
  delay().then(function(){
    return delay(3000); // delay 3 sec
  }).then(DoingSmth());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the time stamp of the last action in a variable and check time elapsed between now and last time stamp

```
let lastActionTime = new Date();

let cooldown = () => {
let timeElapsed;
let now = new Date();
//get the actual time elapsed in ms
timeElapsed = now - lastActionTime;
//check if the time elapsed is less than 15 minute or not
if(timeElapsed < 900000){
//if yes, return message with remaining time in seconds
console.log(`You are on cooldown, remaining time ${(900000-timeElapsed)/1000} seconds`);
} else {
//Do the requested action and re-assign the lastActionTime
console.log(`Hurray`);
lastActionTime = new Date();
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest to save this timestamp in a map—or the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this in a SPA(Single Page Application) is to save the time of expiration in a global state (Redux in React for example) - this way the user can move through pages and the "countdown" will still work

If your app is not a SPA you can save the expiration date in your database.

Regarding the other answers that suggest implementing the functionality on the same page - it is not feasible to expect the user to remain on the same page for 15 minutes.